# Locust: No statistics shown

Tags: python, locust

I'm new to Locust, and I am attempting to log statistics for a POST request, and I'm using the following code along with a generic call to `locust`.

```
import json

from locust import HttpUser, task, between
import cfg

class BasicUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 3)
    v1_data = json.load(open("v1_sample_data.json", "r"))

    @task
    def get_v1_prediction(self):
        route = "/" + cfg.lookup("model.v1.route")
        response = self.client.post(
            route,
            json=self.v1_data,
            catch_response=True,
            name="API Call"
        )
        print(response.text)
```

When I start an experiment, the host is called successfully, and `response.text` has the expected value and is printed to the console repeatedly. However, the statistics aren't logged.

When I use a GET request in place of the POST without passing data, statistics are logged (though it's only failures because the web app only allows POST requests). Any idea what's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `catch_response=True` is the culprit.

[From the documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/2.13.0/api.html#locust.clients.HttpSession.request):

> catch_response – (optional) Boolean argument that, if set, can be used to make a request return a context manager to work as argument to a with statement. This will allow the request to be marked as a fail based on the content of the response, even if the response code is ok (2xx). The opposite also works, one can use catch_response to catch a request and then mark it as successful even if the response code was not (i.e 500 or 404).